# About uniqueness of lifted paths in the phath lifting theorem in fiber bundles

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, fiber-bundles

Im trying to understand the path lifting theorem (in the context of locally trivial fiber bundles presented in the book "Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications", by Jerrold E. Marsden *et. al.*), stated as follows:

Let $\pi : E \to B$ a $C^{0}$ locally trivial fiber bundle and let $c: [0,1] \to B $ be a continuous path starting at $c(0)=b_0$. Then for each $c_0 \in \pi^{-1}(b_0)$ there is a unique continuous path $\tilde{c}:[0,1] \to E $ such that $\tilde{c}(0)=c_0$ and $\pi \circ \tilde{c} = c$.

I think a conuterexample of this statement is obtained considering the trivial bundle $\mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}$ with the path $c:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$, given by $c(t)=(\cos{2 \pi t}, \sin{2 \pi t})$. Taking $b_0 = (1,0)$ and $c_0 = (1,0,a) \in \mathbb{R}$, **any** lifted path $\tilde{c}(t)=(\cos{2 \pi t}, \sin{2 \pi t},f(t))$, with $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $f(0)=a$ would fulfill $\pi \circ \tilde{c}$ and $\tilde{c}(0)=c_0$.

In this example the lifting is not unique, and I would appreciate if someone can show me what am I missing or if there is some property or condition missing in the path lifting theorem I quoted above.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I'm sure that $c_0$ is meant to be carried locally constantly through the local trivializations, so it seems a hypothesis is missing.

Comment: This must be a typo. There's no uniqueness of lifted paths unless the typical fiber is a discrete space (and thus $\pi$ is a covering map, at least when $E$ is connected).